# My pc is not booting the pen drive containing ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, usb, wubi

My pc is not booting with the pen drive containing Ubuntu. 
I used Unetbootin to create the pen.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your BIOS is not set to boot your pen drive first. Here's what you need to do.

1. Spam your BIOS key. If you don't know what it is, your computer probably tells you to use it to interrupt startup.
2. Set your pen drive as the first boot option
3. Save and quit
4. Boot your computer
5. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

A more clean option if you only want to do this once (for a repair or backup), you can also press F12 and choose your boot device 
Sometimes this is another key - search for 'select boot device' or 'boot from other disk' when starting.